# EasyPost USPS - How to buy Media Mail shipment?

Tags: c#, .net, usps, easypost

I am able to buy Shipment for Priority using

```
 shipment.Buy(shipment.LowestRate(includeCarriers: new List<string> { "USPS" }, includeServices: new List<string>() { "Priority" }));
```

How can I buy Media Mail instead of Priority?

I tried 
**shipment.Create()**
and checked shipment.rates but there only available option are **Priority** and **Express**.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Options object on a Shipment](https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#options-object). You'll see the `special_rates_eligibility` property where you can pass `USPS.MEDIAMAIL`.